NPM Run Dev on Vite
When I attempt to set up my development server on Vite using "npm run dev", I get the following error:
node:internal/process/promises:289
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^
[Failed to load PostCSS config: Failed to load PostCSS config (searchPath: /Users/jdoran/buoc-app): [Error] EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
at async readFileHandle (node:internal/fs/promises:552:24)
at async Object.search (file:///Users/jdoran/buoc-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-DEPSZ3SS.js:21493:45)] {
errno: -21,
code: 'EISDIR',
syscall: 'read'
}
I do get the link to the server but accessing it results in a network error. What is the error above supposed to mean? I understand the general meaning of EISDIR but I can not tell which directory it refers to as there are several listed.
I have done extensive research on what this problem could be but have had no luck.
